# Distribution of a Filtered Signal

Tags: filters, random

For a given input signal, for each discretized sample, $dt=1$:
$$ x(t) \sim N(0,1)$$

and a given LTI low order filter with transfer function:
$$ H_{fil}(f)$$

**which would be is the a priori distribution of the filtered signal?**
$$ x_{fil}(t) \sim ? $$

this is, not the conditional distribution of the 1 step predictor: 
$$ x_{fil}(t)|x(t-1) \sim ? $$

but the distribution of the $n=t/dt$ steps simulation: 
$$ x_{fil}(t)|x(0) \sim ? $$

**For example**, the special case of the integration:
$$ H_{int}(f)=\frac{1}{2\pi f}$$

has a distribution of the sum of gaussian distribution:
$$ x_{int}(t) \sim N(0,\sqrt{\frac{t}{dt}}) $$

this is a normal distribution, with a variance which increases linearly with the number of samples.