# The Distribution of Filtered Gaussian White Noise

Tags: filters, noise, gaussian, statistics

Suppose I have some time series $s(t)$ which contains Gaussian white noise generated by a distribution $N(0,\sigma^2)$

Then I apply a filter to s(t) with a frequency response $H(\omega)$, giving me $s_H(t)$

What distribution does $s_H(t)$ have?

I'm particularly interested in cases where $s_H(t)$ is band limited Gaussian white noise.

Comment: This question seems to be almost exactly same as the one I'm asking here but sadly, it has no answer:
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/38428/distribution-of-a-filtered-signal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you filter a Gaussian random process with an LTI system, the output will also be Gaussian. You can make intuitive sense of this by considering that a linear combination (which is what filtering does) of jointly Gaussian random variables is a Gaussian random variable.

You can find an in-depth treatment of filtering random processes in [this MIT OpenCourseWare document](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-450-principles-of-digital-communications-i-fall-2006/lecture-notes/book_7.pdf) (section 7.4).

Comment: Reworded second sentence. Please put back if you disagree.